# How to make sure two microservices are in sync

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, microservices

I have a kubernetes solution with lots of microservices. Each microservice has its own database and to send data between the services we use kafka.

I have one microservice that generates lots of orders and order lines.
Theese are saved to the order services own database and every change should be pushed to kafka using a kafka connector setup.
Another microservice with items and prices. All changes are saved to tables in this services database and changes are pushed to their own topic using the kafka connector.

Now I have a third microservice (The calculater) that calculate something based on the data from the previous mentioned services. Right now it just consumes changes from the order, orderline, item and price topics. And when its time it calculates.

The Calculater microservice is scheduled to do the calculation at a certain time each day. But before doing the calculation Id like to know if the service is up to date with data from the other two microservices.

Is there some kind of best practice on how to do this?

What this should make sure is that I havent lost a change. Lets say an orderlines quantity was changed from 100 to 1. Then I want to make sure I have gotten that change before I start calculating.

Comment: What information do you have available between each service to know what is up to date or not? Maybe you need a shared database

Comment: Hi OneCricketeer. My team owns all three microservices so we can have whatever data we want made available. When you mention a shared database I'm thinking about all the downsides like more coupling between the services. But please enlighten me =)

Comment: Not clear with 'Calculator' service, is this pulling data from Oder and Prices microservices? How Calculator receiving the data for calculation?  anyway you can have additional microservice/Kafka listener that will keep track of new changes and trigger Re-Calculation.

Comment: You can use Kafka Streams to join various topics, and that'll essentially create a RocksDB database with the joined data. You could also create your own database with some status field that has states like `incomplete, ready, missing order, missing place`, etc. Filter for ready when you schedule the job. Update the status when you receive either or both events

Comment: More information - https://microservices.io/patterns/data/shared-database.html

Comment: I just updated the question. Hope its more clear what options I have now.
I just read the link regarding the shared database. Hope I can find a solution without having to do that.

Comment: I still think you need to clarify "when its time it calculates". How does it know all information is available or not? You'll need to join the topics _somehow_ to get all the information, and a database is one persistent way to store that information until that point (even if that's Kafka Streams w/ RocksDB)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the `orders` and `items` microservices have all their data published to kafka prior to having the `calculater` execute its logic, that is quite application specific and it may be hard to come up with a good answer without more details. The Kafka connector that sends the orders, order lines and so on messages from the database to Kafka is some kind of CDC connector (so it basically listens to DB table changes and publishes them to Kafka)? If so, most likely you will need some way to compare the latest message in Kafka with the latest row updated to know if the connector has sent all DB updates to Kafka. There may be connectors that expose that information somehow, or you may have to implement something yourself.

On the other side, if what you want is to know if `calculater` has read all the messages that have been published to kafka by the other services, that is easier. You just need to get the high watermarks (the latest offset in each topic) and check that the `calculater` consumer has actually consumed it (so there is no lag). I guess, though, that the topics are continuously updated, so most likely there will always be some lag, but well, there is nothing you can do about that.